# Find first occurrence of today's date and insert row above

Tags: excel, vba, insert, find

The following code inserts a row above the first occurrence of the word Scheduled in column D and then find the first occurrence of the word Roadblocked and insert a row above that.

When I try to find the first occurrence of today's date in Column C and insert a row above it doesn't work.

I plan to continue the code with finding tomorrow's date and insert row above, etc.

```vb
Dim cl As Range

Set cl = Range("D:D").Find("Scheduled")
If Not cl Is Nothing Then cl.Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0).EntireRow.Insert
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3).FormulaR1C1 = "SCHEDULED"

Set cl = Range("D:D").Find("Roadblock")
If Not cl Is Nothing Then cl.Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0).EntireRow.Insert
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -3).FormulaR1C1 = "ROADBLOCKED"
 
Set cl = Range("C:C").Find([Today()])
If Not cl Is Nothing Then cl.Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(0).EntireRow.Insert
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2).FormulaR1C1 = "DUE TODAY"
```

Comment: Possibly unrelated, but judging from your indentation, you are expecting those indented lines to be part of your `If` statement, and they are not. They will run every time whether `cl` is nothing or not.

Comment: @BraX. You're right, I just discovered that. It works fine if it finds "Scheduled" but if it doesn't find it, it just inserts the row at the last selected cell. I tried the Else command to make it skip to the next section if "scheduled" isn't found, but got an error.  I'll have to do some homework to figure it out; or start another post.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the line

```
Set cl = Range("C:C").Find([Today()])
```

with

```
Set cl = Range("C:C").Find(Date)
```

Hopefully, that will be enough. If not, make sure that your date formats are matching. Try a `Debug.Print Date()` to see if VBA agrees with the date format in your cells.